# IIS Application Pool Identity Not Working with .NET CORE?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, iis-7

We have a proxy server that's intercepting requests from our WebServer. This works fine for .Net Framework applications running in IIS, but our .Net Core 2.1 application is getting blocked by the proxy. We tried changing the Application Pool to use a domain user account instead of the ApplicationPoolIdentity, but the .Net Core API doesn't seem to be picking up this account. Requests made using the HttpClient object aren't going through as the domain user.

Is there something we're missing to make sure a .Net Core application using the Application Pool Identity for HttpClient requests?

Comment: Do your domain user account have read/write access to the website directory? you can try to grant the user account permissions to access the required asp files and folders from a command prompt. `aspnet_regiis -ga "Domain\SomeAccount"`.

Comment: @samwu yeah it does. I added the service account to the IIS_USRS group, so it should has the necessary permissions.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?